# Async.whilst callback to which function

Tags: node.js

```
var i = 0;
async.whilst(
    function(){ return i < 5; },

    function(cb) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i++);
            cb();
        }, 1000);
    },

    function(err) { console.err("we encountered an error", err); }
);
```

I saw this code on another stack overflow post and was a little confused by the syntax of this async call. Inside the async.whilst there is a function with the parameter cb: function(cb). Then inside of that function after the setTimeOut call cb() is being called. My question is what function does cb() call back to? Is it simply calling:

```
function(){ return i < 5; }
```

Or is it calling the function(cb) again?

Answer (score 1):

It's calling back to an internal function of `async` that will either stop the loop (if `cb()` got passed an error) or will subsequently start another iteration of the loop.

If you take a look at [the implementation](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/aa2c8896d7e384d1f582c520f4e882617bbb357e/lib/async.js#L751-L767), the `next` variable is the callback function that gets passed to the iterator function.

Comment: So it is calling back at this line: function(){ return i < 5} ?  I am not really sure what the var next = _restParam(function(err, args){...}); means in the implementation.

Comment: @JohnClaydet `next` is the callback that gets passed (and called by your code).